# Can you iterate a list for as long as you want in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot a lot of lists of points in the same plot using pyplot, and I want to do it such that every list is represented with a different color and/or shape. Right now I am doing it as follows:

```
colors=['ro','go','bo','yo','mo','co','ko','rs','gs','bs','ys','ms','cs','ks',
'r*','g*','b*','y*','m*','c*','k*'] #basic dots, stars, colors and square shapes of pyplot

for i in range(len(a)):
     plt.plot(a[i],c[i],random.choice(colors))
plt.show()
```

with `a, c` being some list of lists of numbers with matching size for each pair of lists `a[i],c[i]`.

The problem is that by using `random.choice(colors)` I end up with a series of points in the plot that are close by and do not belong to the same list of numbers but have the same color and shape. Also, there are more lists of numbers to plot than colors in `colors`.

My question is the following: is there a way one can iterate `colors` in order and when it gets to the last term it continues iterating from the first term again? I know I can just join `colors` to itself many times but that is not a very clean way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) will help you out.

Comment: Perhaps you just want `colors[i % len(colors)]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if this works:

```
k=0
colors=['ro','go','bo','yo','mo','co','ko','rs','gs','bs','ys','ms','cs','ks',
'r*','g*','b*','y*','m*','c*','k*'] #basic dots, stars, colors and square shapes of pyplot

for i in range(len(a)):
     if(k==len(colors)):
         k=0
     plt.plot(a[i],c[i],colors[k])
     k+=1
plt.show()
```